# How to generate insert statements from select statements?

Tags: sql, select

Sometimes, I run into a situation where I want to migrate database changes with a simple script. Say, I Inserted **(INPUT)** values e.g.

```
INSERT into mytable (CodeId, ValueData, category) VALUES (3, 4, 'COMPUTERS');
INSERT into mytable (CodeId, ValueData, category) VALUES (3, 12, 'TABLES');
```

How can I can generate back the insert statements with a select statements so I can run a select query like:

```
SELECT (super query) from mytable where CodeId = 3
```

and have something like this as **output**:

```
INSERT into mytable (CodeId, ValueData, category) VALUES  (3, 4, 'COMPUTERS'), (3, 12, 'TABLES') ;
```

**EDIT:**

---

I am currently tring something like this:

```
select concat('insert into mytable (CodeId, ValueData, category)
VALUES (', select (CodeId, ValueData, category) as gstr from mytable, ')')
```

I think it should be something along that line....

Comment: Could you please explain input and output that you want?

Comment: Thought I already explained the output with the example expected result

Comment: Can you use `mysqldump` or `phpMyAdmin`?

Comment: @rtuner You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ for explaining what you are looking for, expected output etc.

Comment: Do you want to display the last executed query?

Answer (score 2):

Completely untested but should get you on the right track...

```
SELECT Concat('INSERT INTO mytable (CodeId, ValueData, category) VALUES', Group_Concat(the_values)) As result
FROM   (
        SELECT Concat('(', CodeId, ', ', ValueData, ', ', category, ')') As the_values
        FROM   mytable
        WHERE  CodeId = 3
       ) As x
```

Comment: I have just changed approach once more. Click on the "edited N mins ago" on the post to see former revisions.

Comment: Thanks, but says: `concat is not a recognized inbuilt function.`

Comment: What DBMS are you using? I could have sworn it said MySQL somewhere... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: Hmm, just tested in [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/258862/1) and it works surprisingly, but it doesn't work on mysql IDE.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was actually trying this in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Select CodeId, ValueData, category 
into DESTTableName  
from mytable where CodeId=3;
```

Comment: This will only work once and if DESTTableName does not exist already.

Comment: @bhs- Yeah, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for this type of insert would be:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(CodeId, ValueData, category)
SELECT CodeId, ValueData, category
FROM MYTable
WHERE CodeID=3
```

Your example has you selecting and inserting data into the same table ?

As long as the selected columns match the pattern of the columns you want to input you are fine.